# Can i check is MouseClick inside certain area?

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I have PictureBox in my Windows Form.When I click in some part of the picture, some label text needs to be changed.
Is there any way to know is it clicked in some part of the image?
I didn't gave any code because i think you can understand my problem whitout it.

Comment: If you need non-rectangular areas you can use GraphicsPath and build up a List<GraphicsPath> of them.  It has a similar IsVisible() method like Contains() in Rectangle below.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have `rect` as your `Rectangle` with some initialization, its coordinates are relative to your `PictureBox`:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(rect.Contains(e.Location)){
       //your code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create mapping for your image, something like this:

```
Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(/*coordinates of part of image*/);
OnClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (rect1.Contains(e.Location))
  {
     //handler for this part
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create List of `Rectangle` containing areas you want to be interactive.

let say:

`private static List<Rectangle> rects`;

populate it with desired coordinates in some order.

then in OnClick event

```
OnClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    for(int i=0; i<rects.Count; i++)
        if (r.Contains(e.Location))
            ActionForArea(i);    
}
```

also

```
private static void ActionForArea(int number)
{
    //do sth
}
```